# How can we avoid entering the path of every different file each time in a shell script?

Tags: bash

I have to submit a script for slurm. I should enter the directory path whenever I change the submit script path. for example if I am in `folder1` I should write manually:

```
/home/job/folder1
```

if I want to use the script in `folder2` I should write:

```
/home/job/folder2
```

Is there any command to avoid making this change manually?

PS: I know I can use $pwd but I did not find the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With `$PWD`

- `PWD` is an environment variable that is updated to contain the current directory,
- `$variable` is replaced by the value of `variable`

This gives:

```
thescript $PWD
```

#### With `$(pwd)`

- `pwd` is a command that prints the current directory
- `$(command)` is replaced by the output of `command`

This gives:

```
thescript $(pwd)
```

Comment: @PRATAP No, as explained, they are two different things.